# how to pass DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> object from one Activity to another

Tags: android, api, authentication, android-activity, dropbox

I want a second Activity to use the DropboxAPI object (mApi here) and invoke the Dropbox api methods....

how can i pass it....

```
basket.putParcelable("key", mApi);
```

basket being a Bundle object..

has the error"The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, DropboxAPI)"

would casting work??`basket.putParcelable("key", (Parcelable) mApi);`

is it possible to send it as a Bundle??

please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>` class does not `implement Parcelable` in it's code, you can't put it in an `Intent`. You can only put `Parcelable` objects. If you have access to the source, you should make it implement `Parcelable`.

This is a [good place](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to start

Comment: I do not have the source for  DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> class..

So does that mean,i just have to do with the single Activity where the Authentication was made...

Comment: Well, you can't put it in an Intent without Parcelling it first. So you can't use Intents. You would have to come with a different approach. You could do it the way you suggested it yourself.